# Magento2: Multiple stores (groups) under single website

Tags: magento2, multistore

I want to have a single `website` with a single domain/URL. Under that `website` I want to have two `stores`, each of which will have one single `store view`.

One store is intended for regular browser clients, and the other store is for clients which use a specific mobile app which has its own browser with a unique user agent. The people I'm building this for want to showcase different products in that app.

I'm running Magento2 with nginx 1.8 and php-fpm 7.0

I thought I could set this up by modifying my index.php as seen in numerous examples. Even [the official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html) shows this, saying that I need to set `MAGE_RUN_TYPE` to either `store` or `website` and `MAGE_RUN_CODE` to the one that I want.

My problem is that I cannot figure out what to set as value for `MAGE_RUN_CODE`! Looking in the backend and database, `stores` (db table `store_group`) don't have a `code`! Only `websites` and `store views` have a `code`, and every single example I can find on the internet uses `MAGE_RUN_TYPE`=`'website'` which doesn't help me.

How do I tell Magento which store I want to show?

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't need to do anything **`MAGE_RUN_TYPE='website'`** for your requirements.

Its needed when you have to require two different websites with differnt domain name.

In your case you doen't need two different domain so you dont need to do changes in index.php file.

Comment: I know that I don't need `MAGE_RUN_TYPE='website'`, in my question I complained that every example on the internet is always about that, but never about what I need. If I don't need to change `index.php` then how do I tell the system which `store` to use?